# Matrix exponential with Armadillo

Tags: c++, matlab, lapack, armadillo

I am currently developing with my own C++/Mex code and Matlab, but my project is getting big and I am considering switching to a proper linear algebra library. I have read very good things about Armadillo, but I can't find a few essential functions I need for my project.

I understand Armadillo links to LAPACK and BLAS libraries, but I couldn't find the matrix exponential function in [Armdaillo's API](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html), nor in the [LAPACK functions](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/lapacke.html#_function_list).

Can anyone tell me if there is an add-on to compute matrix exponentials with Armadillo? If so, a short example code would be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you considering moving to C++ entirely? It's not clear from the wording of your question - Matlab has matrix exponential, and you mention developing Mex C++ functions.

Comment: @bogeyc I am working with both Matlab and C++ (I am a research student). The C++ part is essentially independent of Matlab, but I write wrapper Mex functions to be called from Matlab for better processing speed or for processing that require very large amounts of memory. Switching to a library would be for the C++ part, and Armadillo matrices can handle matrices allocated with Matlab (part of the reason why I'm considering it).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has been added as `expmat` to the latest release, see
http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#expmat

Answer (score 4):

The matrix exponential is something Matlab has. So [Octave](http://www.octave.org) implemented it. So other Free Software projects looked at what [Octave](http://www.octave.org) has and reimplemented it by borrowing this implementation.

I work a lot with [R](http://www.r-project.org) and [Armadillo](http://arma.sf.net) via the [RcppArmadillo](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rcpp.armadillo.html) package (for which I'm a co-author).  In one piece of recent work I needed `expm()` and borrowed it for use by [Armadillo](http://arma.sf.net) from the [R package exmp](http://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/expm/index.html).

The code goes like this:

```
arma::mat expm(arma::mat x) {
    arma::mat z(x.n_rows, x.n_cols);
    (*expmat)(x.begin(), x.n_rows, z.begin(), Ward_2);
    return z;
}
```

but it hinges of course on the fact that I get the function pointer to `expmat` from the 
[R package exmp](http://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/expm/index.html). The full file [is here on Github](https://github.com/eddelbuettel/rcppkalman/blob/master/src/expmMat.cpp) which has the enum `Ward_2` as well.

Comment: Thank you, at the moment I'm using `mexCallMATLAB( 1, &_expmat, 1, &_mxmat, "expm" );` with Matlab, but it is quite slow. I could keep the same trick too, but I was wondering if there was a better way.

Comment: Yes, we can call back into R as _but prefer to avoid it as much as possible_.  So worst case I think you may have to go the full way and implement expm in Armadillo.  Which you could contribute to Conrad's growing body of work :)

Comment: Alright then, I might do that when I have more time, I see recurrent questions about matrix exponentials and the answer is almost always "look at Nineteen Dubious Ways ... and DIY". For now, I might just go with my Matlab trick, but thanks a lot for sharing your experience! :)

Answer (score 3):

Here's a port of John Burkardt's c/c++ implementation of one of the 19 dubious to Armadillo...

https://gist.github.com/tesch1/0c03e43885cd66eceabe

Comment: Good to know! I will check it out when I have a moment, thanks